# Problem with The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting this error of The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(), at this following code, basically I am trying to index to index comparison:

```
data["observation"] = "Class 1" if (data["Result1"] > data["Result2"]) else "Class 2"
```

I tried using empty, but the result doesn't seem right, similar to any and all, the result is not what I want.

How to correct it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data["observation"] = pd.np.where(data["Result1"] > data["Result2"], "Class 1", "Class 2")
```

That works if you imported `pandas` as `pd` (using `import pandas as pd`), otherwise, if you just used `import pandas`, then use `pandas.np.where(...)`

Alternatively, to use the list comprehension syntax, which is what I think you were trying to do, use:

```
data["observation"]=["Class 1" if i["Result1"] >i["Result2"] else "Class 2" for _, i in data.iterrows()]
```

However, this could be very inneficient for a large dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! the where syntax works perfect! However, if I now want to add another condition, data["observation"] = pd.np.where(data["Result1"] > data["Result2"] and data["Time"] == "12:00", "Class 1", "Class 2"), it does not work and I got the same error as before. It is also true if I use bitwise operator &

Comment: Even with proper parentheses? For instance: `pd.np.where((data["Result1"] > data["Result2"]) & (data["Time"] == "12:00"), "Class 1", "Class 2")`?

Comment: I didn't bracket the second condition, it works with proper parentheses, many thanks for pointing this out.